# what kind of type hint for status code and message

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

Which return value type to use in

```
def create_or_update_gp(data: UpdateSchema) -> HERE:
    try:
        ....logic...
            return 200, {'message': 'successfully updated'}
    except Exception as ex:
        return 400, {'message': 'Update error'}
```

I can write something like `Tuple[str, dict]` looks pretty general. Perhaps there is a special format for status codes? Or am I overcomplicating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `HTTPStatus` enumeration from `from http import HTTPStatus` instead of an integer and a `Tuple[HTTPStatus, dict]` as the full type hint

Comment: looks just right , but `mypy` return `Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[int, Dict[str, str]]", expected "Tuple[HTTPStatus, Dict[str, str]]")`

Comment: Did you keep the original "return 200" or did you update it to "return HTTPStatus.OK"?

Comment: original return "200"

Comment: seems like `Tuple[int, Dict[str, str]]` suitable alternative